# how to run thymeleaf project example using maven and how to download it

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

Hello My friends I am trying to learn thymeleaf from the project documentation but I run into problem when I try to download their project example there is no download button and I can not find the requirement to run the project from github it only say use maven so can you show me how to run thyemleaf project example the link for the project example is [link](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/tree/3.1-master/examples/core/thymeleaf-examples-gtvg-jakarta) the site I am using to lean is this [site](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html) so my question is very simple how to run this project in order to see the code inside it.

Comment: @andrewJames I did thank you but still the issue of running this kind of projects

Answer (score 0):

To run the Thymeleaf "Good Thymes Virtual Grocery" demo project, you can follow these steps:

1. Download the zip file from [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf). Click on the green "Code" button and choose "Download ZIP".

(You can choose to clone the repository instead of downloading the zip file.)

2. Unzip the zip file (e.g. using 7-Zip or a similar tool).
3. Open a command window (e.g. the CMD prompt if you are using Windows, or a command shell in Linux, etc.) At the command prompt, `cd` to the unzipped directory `thymeleaf-3.1-master` and then to the sub-directory `examples/core/thymeleaf-examples-gtvg-jakarta`.
4. At the command prompt in the `thymeleaf-examples-gtvg-jakarta` directory, run the following command, as instructed [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.1-master/examples/core/thymeleaf-examples-gtvg-jakarta/HOW_TO_RUN.txt):

```
mvn clean verify cargo:run
```

If you do not have Maven installed, then [download](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and [install](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) it first, and make sure its `bin` directory is part of your `PATH` - otherwise the above `mvn` command will fail.

5. You will see the project being built and started. At the end, you will see:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 10.x started on port [8080]
```

6. Open the following URL in a browser: `http://localhost:8080`

You should see the demo home page:

[image]

---

If the above process does not work, then please ask a new, more specific question with detailed error information.